# Trigger function of link with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm triying call href function when I press enter, I have the index row where the a href is.

```
switch(e.which) {
 case 13{
         $('#tableName tbody tr a').eq(indexRow).unbind().click();
        }
```

Comment: On enter do you want to open the link in a new tab? Is that your requirement? Please elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: The table is inside a dialog, the javascript contains parameters When I press enter Those parameters are send to the main view .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem then below code may solve your issue:

```
switch(e.which) {
     case 13:
             window.location = $('#tableName tbody tr a').eq(indexRow).attr("href");
     break;
}
```

Please ley me know if you will face any issue.